# How to redirect a user in react native after Json response from your login api

Tags: json, react-native, redirect, expo

Please I am building an app with react native, I code the login api with php, but I have an issue with redirecting the user after successful login to the dashboard, here is my code below

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
export default class SignIn extends Component
{

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({

});
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {username: "",password: "" };
  }

  SignUp = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('CreateAccount')
  };

  InsertRecord = () => {
    var username = this.state.username;
    var password = this.state.password;

    if (username=="") {
    
   alert("Username field cannot be empty")
    return false;
    }
    else if(password==""){
        
        alert("Password field cannot be empty")
    }
    else{
        var InsertAPIURL ='https://moneystackng.com/api/login_api.php';

        var headers={
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
          };
          var Data = {
            username:username,
            password:password

          };

          fetch(InsertAPIURL,
            {
                method:'POST',
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(Data),
            })
            .then((response)=>response.json())
            .then((response)=>{
                    if(response == true){
                    
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
                        params: {
                            screen: 'Dashboard',
                          }
                    });
                 }
                 else{
                    alert(response[0].Message);
                }
                })
                .catch((error)=>
                {
                    alert("Error"+error);
                });
    }
}
```

where I am having issues with is

```
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
                        params: {
                            screen: 'Dashboard',
                          }
                    });
```

please anyone who could help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect user to a page after succesful login in React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883037/redirect-user-to-a-page-after-succesful-login-in-react-app)

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Home", {
   params: {
      screen: 'Dashboard',
   }
});
```

is navigating to the "Home" page with the "params" object, to navigate to u have to:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard");
```

And if you want to send some information to the dashboard you can pass an object after the page name:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard", {foo: bar});
```